# ARCore - Augment Images increase stability of tracking

Tags: arcore

According to the official documentation [Recognize and Augment Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/)

> Beginning with ARCore 1.9, if your image will never move from its
>   position (for example, a poster affixed to a wall), you can attach a
>   global anchor to the image to increase the stability of tracking.

but no further hints or instructions of how to actually do it in code is given. Please advice.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question elsewhere? I'm also looking for this information, but it is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

What they probably meant is to create a normal anchor.

```
Trackable.createAnchor()
```

This will force ARCore to keep more data related to that location in memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an anchor attached to an image like this:

```js
 // Create a new anchor for newly found images.
          if (!augmentedImageMap.containsKey(augmentedImage)) {
            AugmentedImageNode node = new AugmentedImageNode(this);
            node.setImage(augmentedImage);
            augmentedImageMap.put(augmentedImage, node);
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(node);
          }
          break;
```

See a full example including the above extract in the Sceneforms here: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmentedimage/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageActivity.java

Hosting an anchor as a cloud anchor is described in detail in an ARCore code lab - see link here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-cloud-anchors/#2

It is worth looking at the whole codelab as it is short and clear, but the key line to host the anchor you create is below:

```js
snackbarHelper.showMessage(getActivity(), "Now hosting anchor...");
cloudAnchorManager.hostCloudAnchor(
    getArSceneView().getSession(), anchor, this::onHostedAnchorAvailable);
```

Comment: The question was not how to create an anchor, but rather to attach a _global_ anchor, as described in the documentation.

Comment: @AndersEmil - there is actually no specific ARCore entity called a 'Global Anchor' so if the OP wanted an anchor which is available in the 'world' of the app, the first part of the answer shows this as it is not covered in the link the OP provided, If the request is for a 'Cloud Anchor' then I've updated the answer to provide some info on cloud anchors also.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with cloud anchors